# Is it possible to manually change a value associated with an id?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was just playing with `id()` function in iPython console. So let's say we have variables `foo` and `bar`:

```
foo = 2
id(foo)

Out[38]: 2007329888

bar = 4
id(bar)

Out[40]: 2007329952
```

So, unsurprisingly, `foo` and `bar` have different ids. And if we change `bar` to have a value of 2 both variables will now have the same id:

```
bar = 2
id(bar)

Out[42]: 2007329888

id(foo)
Out[43]: 2007329888
```

Ok, now we change both variables to have some other value. Now id 2007329888 is not associated with any variable:

```
foo = bar = True

id(foo)
Out[45]: 2006839456

id(bar)
Out[46]: 2006839456
```

But then if we assign a new variable a value of 2, it will get linked to that same old id:

```
bla = 2

id(bla)
Out[48]: 2007329888
```

So, my questions from all this are:

1. How does Python decide when a value associated with an id is no longer needed and can be written over or are all ids and associated value kept until the end of the session?
2. Is it possible to manually specify and overwrite value associated with an id? (I'm pretty sure the answer is a 'no', but just want to check.)

Thanks!

Comment: Please, see [this information](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong). I'm not quite sure if the same applies for iPython implementation, but it looks like so. I doesn't exactly answer none of your 2 questions, but it is a good point to start understanding how Python works on that regard.

Comment: An I'd merely represents  unique object. So whenever you have a different object, it will have a new ID, although, that is only guaranteed for the lifetime of the object

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, but how is the lifetime of an object defined?

Comment: @pavel What do you mean? You create an object, `f = Foo()`, the *python language* merely requires that once an object is no longer referenced/reachable, it is free to be garbage collected. In the CPython implementation, which uses reference counting, an object will be reclaimed as *soon* as it's reference count reaches zero. So, let's say I don't assign it to anything, `Foo()` then the object is created, then immediately destroyed. Let's say I do something like `mylist = [Foo()]`, there is one reference to my foo object, then I do `mylist.pop()`, now there are zero, it is gone.

Comment: @revliscano IPython isn't a python implementation, it is a specialized REPL that uses the standard CPython implementation.

Comment: "Is it possible to manually specify and overwrite value associated with an id? (I'm pretty sure the answer is a 'no', but just want to check.)" You can use things like `ctypes` to reach into lower-level implementation details like that, although, unless you are a fan of segfaults, I wouldn't suggest doing that.

Comment: Note, `id`s **are not associated with variables**. They are *associated with objects*.

Comment: Big thanks for that clarification, @juanpa.arrivillaga I thought it was a different implementation than CPython. I appreciate it.

Comment: With all that information spread, I would kindly ask you to add an answer that condensates all that. Please, I'm sure that more than one person would benefit from those insights. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Thanks for all the insights everyone! Now there's some reading for me to do.